# Can't create MVC controller ,using as a class from a class library as a model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, class-library

The problem I'm having is: I have 2 class libraries, one is named LocalsLibrary and the other is the SensorsLibrary.

SensorsLibrary has a reference to LocalsLibrary, yet  on my Web API and my Client MVC ,  since I can't add reference to both classLibraries which would make a circle loop, I am adding the SensorsLibrary as the reference. The problem is, I want to create in both API and Client, Controllers of the class's in both classLibraries, but it only recognizes the ones in the SensorsLibrary.

I'd like to know how can I avoid this problem, and how should I fix this , thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't see why you can't add references to both `LocalsLibaray` and `SensorsLibrary`. If both libraries have a class with the same name you'll need to use the full namespace to use the class e.g. `LocalsLibrary.MyController`.

Comment: I can't do so, because one Library is referring the other one, I just followed a tutorial to guide me

Comment: There is no specific restriction from preventing those references. Perhaps showing us more details about the classes you are trying to use will help others understand your problem.